# Run a powershell script when file contents do not match folder names

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a Powershell script that only runs when the file contents of a .txt file match the name of a folder in a different folder. I don't know if I over complicated the script, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```cs
$From = "c:\test folder\content"
$To = "c:\test folder\archive\new"
$Content = Get-Content -path "c:\Test Folder\Content\content.txt" | Out-String
$Archive = Get-ChildItem -path "c:\Test Folder\Archive\" -name | Out-String

If($Archive -notin $Content){ 
#gets child items and copies them to a new folder
Get-ChildItem $From -recurse | Copy-Item -destination $To
#gets content of file
$Text = Get-Content -path 'c:\test folder\archive\new\content.txt' 
#renames the item
Rename-item -Path 'c:\test folder\archive\new' -NewName $Text
}
```

Comment: So if the files contents reference a folder that the file itself is not in then something has to happen? Do you have a sample of file? I do not see any logic for this in the script?

Comment: @Matt Yes. If the file contents do not equal a folder name in another structure it should run the code. `Get-ChildItem $From -recurse | Copy-Item -destination $To
#gets content of file
`$Text = Get-Content -path 'c:\test folder\archive\new\content.txt' `
#renames the item
`Rename-item -Path 'c:\test folder\archive\new' -NewName $Text
}`

Comment: I think I get it better now. What is wrong with the script? I could see this being a problem `If($Archive -notin $Content)`

Comment: @Matt currently while I'm testing it the `-notin` should evaluate to false then not run the script, but for whatever reason it is evaluating to true and trying to run the script which results in an error because the folder already exists with that name.

Comment: Oh that condition will sort of do what you want but I was trying to caution its use since it is an array operator and not a string comparion operator.

Comment: @Matt I attempted using `-notcontains` but I'm coming up with the same result. Eventually, once this is used multiple times it should build a list of folders with names that will need to be compared to the content.txt file prior running the script.

Comment: `-notcontains` is also an array operator so the caveat still applies. There names are unfortunately misleading so it catches people. You should look into `-like` and possibly `-match` noting that the latter supports REGEX

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you want to see happen? (Folder name, `.txt` contents).  You want to use `-notmatch` and regex to compare the folder name with contents of the `.txt` files.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content | Out-String` is going to output an object of one string rather than an array of strings.

Example Text file with 3 lines:

```
(Get-Content -path Example.txt | Out-String).count
1
(Get-Content -path Example.txt).count
3
```

This means that when you do the array compare after using `Out-String` on the text file with `-in` / `-contains` is basically doing `-eq`.

As Matt suggests in the comments you could use wildcard or regex operators to look for the name inside the larger string.

```
$Content = Get-Content -path "c:\Test Folder\Content\content.txt" -Raw
$Archive = Get-ChildItem -path "c:\Test Folder\Archive\" -Name

If($Content -notmatch $Archive){
```

Alternatively, with the assumption that the Archive name is a row in the file. You could get rid of the `Out-String` and just use `Get-Content` to get the array of strings and use the array comparisons.

```
$Content = Get-Content -path "c:\Test Folder\Content\content.txt"
$Archive = Get-ChildItem -path "c:\Test Folder\Archive\" -Name

If($Archive -notin $Content ){
```